# How does this code not sot my data from a file?

Tags: python

```
f=open("classa2.txt", "r")
data=f.read()
sorted(data)
print(data)
```

This file is mean to sort my data but it does nothing, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You have the inverse from the duped post; you are using `sorted()` and expected it to sort in-place vs. using `list.sort()` and expecting it to return the sorted data. Still, the post there answers your question too.

Comment: `data = f.read()` gives you a string so it will sort single character at a time. Like `sorted('102030')` gives you `['0','0','0','1','2','3']` and also string may also contain new lines `\n`.

Comment: so how would i stop this VIVI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) is not in-place. It will only return a sorted list. You will have to assign it back

```
data = sorted(data)
```

This will overwrite the contents of `data` after sorting.

```
f=open("classa2.txt", "r")
data=f.readlines()
data=sorted(data)
print(data)
```

To print the contents of a list, you have to do

```
for i in data:
    print(i.strip('\n'))
```

Comment: That printed ['\n', '\n', ' ', ' ', "'", "'", "'", "'", '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '6', '7', ':', ':', '[', '[', ']', ']', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'm', 's']
even though james:[4.0] and gib[5.0] is in the file

Comment: this just prints the same thing but downwards

Comment: i tried that but it still leaves the /n's in

Comment: this may be asking too much but how would a do a reverse sort of this?

Comment: @jimbob I've given you the link, it contains everything. Check it first. (To reverse you have to do `sorted(data, reverse = True)`